# Looking for the easiest way to add values to the list in subdictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Looking for the easiest way to add values in subdictionaries. An example:

```
dict1 = { 
    "l": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, 
    "s": {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}, 
    "d": {"a": 7, "b": 8, "c": 9} }
```

I want to create output:

```
{"a": [1, 4, 7], "b": [2, 5, 8], "c": [3, 6, 9]}
```

Stuff that doesn't work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = { 
    "l": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, 
    "s": {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}, 
    "d": {"a": 7, "b": 8, "c": 9} } 

new_dict = defaultdict(list)

for k in dict1:
    d2 = dict1.get(k)
    for k, v in d2.items():
        new_dict[k].append[v]
```

**Output:** TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

I did also something like this:

```
dict1 = { 
    "l": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, 
    "s": {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}, 
    "d": {"a": 7, "b": 8, "c": 9} } 

final_dict = {}
# list_dict = []

for k, v in dict1.items():
    dict_new = dict1[k]
    list_dict = []
    for new_k, new_v in dict_new.items():
        list_dict.append(new_v)
        final_dict[new_k] = list_dict
        print("list_dict ", list_dict)
print("final_dict", final_dict)
```

...but the **output** is:
`{'a': [7, 8, 9], 'b': [7, 8, 9], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}`

When I put `list_dict = []` outside for loop, then the output is:
`{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}`

I wonder do I need some sort of recursion method here to group by all sub-keys (a, b, c) and append all related values, or maybe there is a need for dictionary comprehension.

Comment: `new_dict[k].append[v]` should be `new_dict[k].append(v)` - you're not calling the method (as you should), you're trying to index into it as a list/dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output suggests you want to loop over the values of `dict1`. One option is to use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(list)
for d in dict1.values():
    for k,v in d.items():
        out[k].append(v)
out = dict(out)
```

Another option is to use `cytoolz.dicttoolz.merge_with`:

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge_with
out = merge_with(list, *dict1.values())
```

Yet another option is to use `operator.itemgetter` in a comprehension:

```
from operator import itemgetter
vals = list(dict1.values())
keys = chain.from_iterable(map(dict.keys, vals))
out = {k: list(map(itemgetter(k), vals)) for k in keys}
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 4, 7], 'b': [2, 5, 8], 'c': [3, 6, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`new_dict[k].append[v]` should be `new_dict[k].append(v)` - you're not calling the method (as you should), you're trying to index into it as a list/dict. There is also no reason to look up the value of `k` in the dict immediately after iterating it - you can use `values()` to get only the values instead.

```
for inner_dict in dict1.values():
    for k, v in inner_dict.items():
        new_dict[k].append(v)
```

Comment: Hi. True. I mistakenly placed the wrong type of parenthesis. <facepalm>. Thx for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answers, if you wished to do this in an one-liner you could do it as such:

```
dict1 = { 
    "l": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, 
    "s": {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}, 
    "d": {"a": 7, "b": 8, "c": 9}
}

out = dict(zip(dict1.keys(), map(list, zip(*map(dict.values, dict1.values())))))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'l': [1, 4, 7], 's': [2, 5, 8], 'd': [3, 6, 9]}
```